# I don't know why the same code works for Julia but not work for Mandelbrot?

Tags: python, fractals, mandelbrot

I have the following code that generates a Mandelbrot image. The white spaces around the image, which has to be gotten rid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from numpy import NaN

def mandelbrot(C):
    z = 0
    for n in range(1, 10):
        z = z**2 + C
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return n
    return NaN

def plot():
    X = np.arange(-2.0, 1.0, 0.05)
    Y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.05)
    pixel = np.zeros((len(Y), len(X)))

    for x_iter, x in enumerate(X):
        for y_iter, y in enumerate(Y):
            pixel[y_iter, x_iter] = mandelbrot(x + 1j * y)

        imshow(pixel, cmap = 'gray', extent = (X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()))

    return pixel

pixel = mandelbrot(-0.7 + 0.27015j)
plt.axis('off')  
plot()
plt.show()

from PIL import Image
min_value = np.nanmin(pixel)
max_value = np.nanmax(pixel)
pixel_int = (255*(pixel-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)).astype(np.uint8)
# sample LUT from matplotlib
lut = (plt.cm.viridis(np.arange(256)) * 255).astype(np.uint8) # CHOOSE COLORMAP HERE viridis, jet, rainbow
pixel_rgb = lut[pixel_int]
# changing NaNs to a chosen color
nan_color = [0,0,0,0] # Transparent NaNs
for i,c in enumerate(nan_color):
  pixel_rgb[:,:,i] = np.where(np.isnan(pixel),c,pixel_rgb[:,:,i])
# apply LUT and display
img = Image.fromarray(pixel_rgb, 'RGBA')

print(pixel)
```

But it turns out IndexError: too many indices for array for the line

```
pixel_rgb[:,:,i] = np.where(np.isnan(pixel),c,pixel_rgb[:,:,i])
```

Please, how to fix it?

Actually, in order to get rid of the white spaces around the image the same code (same line) had worked for Julia instead of Mandelbrot a few weeks ago. The following code that generates the Julia image is getting rid of the white spaces around the image.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def julia(C):
    X = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.05)
    Y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.05)
    pixel = np.zeros((len(Y), len(X)))

    for x_iter, x in enumerate(X):
        for y_iter, y in enumerate(Y):
            z = x + 1j * y
            intensity = np.nan
            r = np.empty((100, 100)) # Unused at the moment
            for n in range(1, 1024):
                if abs(z) > 2:
                    intensity = n
                    break
                z = z**2 + C
            pixel[y_iter, x_iter] = intensity
            r.fill(intensity) # Unused at the moment

    # We return pixel matrix
    return pixel

# Compute Julia set image
pixel = julia(-0.7 + 0.27015j)

# Plotting
print(pixel)
plt.show()

from PIL import Image
min_value = np.nanmin(pixel)
max_value = np.nanmax(pixel)  
#want to set all the 255 pixels to removed
pixel_int = (255*(pixel-min_value)/(max_value-min_value)).astype(np.uint8)
# sample LUT from matplotlib,If lut is not None it must be an integer giving the number of entries desired in the lookup table
lut = (plt.cm.viridis(np.arange(256)) * 255).astype(np.uint8) # CHOOSE COLORMAP HERE viridis, jet, rainbow
pixel_rgb = lut[pixel_int]
# changing NaNs to a chosen color
nan_color = [0,0,0,0] # Transparent NaNs
for i,c in enumerate(nan_color):
  pixel_rgb[:,:,i] = np.where(np.isnan(pixel),c,pixel_rgb[:,:,i])
# apply LUT and display
img = Image.fromarray(pixel_rgb, 'RGBA')
img.save('julia.tiff')
Image.open('julia.tiff').show()
print(min_value, max_value)
```

Now, I just don't know why this code of getting rid of the white space around the image doesn't work for the Mandelbrot?! Please help me to figure out the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Your direct problem is that in the Julia case, `pixel_rgb` is a three dimensional array, where in the Mandelbrot case, `pixel_rgb` is a one dimensional array.  So you're trying to apply a three dimensional transform to each of them, and this blows up for the Mandelbrot case, because what you're operating on has only a single dimension, not three.

I don't have more time to completely understand and play with your code, but in the Mandelbrot case, it seems that the `mandelbrot()` function only returns a single value, where the `julia()` function returns a 2D array.  It is the `plot()` function that returns a 2D array in the Mandelbrot case.  So my quick guess at the change you want to make is to change this:

```
pixel = mandelbrot(-0.7 + 0.27015j)
plt.axis('off')
plot()
```

to this:

```
# pixel = mandelbrot(-0.7 + 0.27015j)
plt.axis('off')
pixel = plot()
```

This allows the Mandelbrot code to run without crashing.  I don't know if it's doing exactly what you want though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve! Your guess ready work for the case, that is X = np.arange(-2.0, 1.0, 0.005) and Y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, 0.005)

Comment: Cool.  Please mark this as the answer by clicking the checkmark if you think it solved your problem, or upvote it if it only partially answered it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Steve, your guess that works well for the case  X = np.arange(-2.0, 1.0, **0.005**), Y = np.arange(-1.5, 1.5, **0.005**). But, I don’t know why it doesn’t work for the case **0.001**,**0.002**! memory error occurs when I used  **0.001** instead of **0.005** to obtain an image with 3000x3000pixels for application purpose. This means that my program somehow creates too many objects by using **pixel = plot()**, what should I do for resolve this memory error? Steve!

Comment: The only thing you can do is write code that is more efficient with memory but does the same thing.  My guess is that a Numpy array is inefficient memory-wise because its designed for easy manipulation of data and the ability to store all different kinds of data and is not interested in memory efficiency.  My approach would be to process a single line of pixels with Numpy, but then convert the line to a simple Python array.  This simple array would take up much less memory.  So you'd use Numpy to process each line, but you wouldn't store the whole image using Numpy structures.

Comment: I just couldn't think of any code that would do me more efficient with memory.  Steve, do you know what are those and how to apply them to the code?

Comment: No, off hand I don't know.  I don't have any direct experience with Numpy.  I think you should try to find someone who is who can help you.  Maybe you should submit a second question that asks specifically about the memory usage issue.